# Flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: ios, list, flutter, casting, decode

I need to assign a model to a list in the application, but I am getting the error I mentioned in the title.

Although I get this error on the android side, I do not have a problem, but when I try it on the ios side, my application crashes.

```
List<MessageModel> messageList = [];
String? message;
bool success = false;

@override
MessageService decode(dynamic data) {
messageList = (data as List).map((e) => MessageModel.fromJsonData(e)).toList(); ----> Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is `data` is null.

Try my solution:

```
List<MessageModel> messageList = [];
String? message;
bool success = false;

@override
MessageService decode(dynamic data) {
  messageList = data?.map((e) => MessageModel.fromJsonData(e))?.toList() ?? [];
  return this;
}
```

Comment: now my list doesnt get anymore and get [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'DioError' in type cast
 errors

Comment: what is your `data`'s type?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it as nullable:

```
List<MessageModel> ?messageList = [];
```